# Linux or Mac: merging columns from different files mixes the columns

Tags: linux

I am trying to use "`paste`" command to merge columns from few files but it makes a bad merge as follows. I appreciate your help.

**File1.csv**:

A   2

B   3

C   4

**File2.csv**:

AA   6

BB   8

CC   2

**output** expected(required):

A 2 AA 6

B 3 BB 8

C 4 CC 2

The **command** I used:

```
paste File1.csv File2.csv > output.csv
```

also used

```
paste -d'\t' File1.csv File2.csv > output.csv
```

**output.csv**(wrong output that I get):

A  2
      AA  6

B  3
      BB  8

C  4
      CC  2

Thanks. I appreciate your help.

Comment: if MS-Windows was involved in creating or transporting files (thru ftp for example), you probably now have `\r\n` line endings. Use `dos2unix file1 file2 file3 fileN` to clean them up. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very much fine. I managed to install it :) and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shellter solution worked very well which is using 'dos2unix' command.

```
dos2unix file1 file2 file3 fileN
```